# Make wp_list_pages print slugs instead of titles

Tags: slug, wp-list-pages, walker

By default wp_list_pages spits out an unordered list of post titles. To save space in a sidebar menu I´m trying to create a list of page slugs instead of page titles.

I suppose I´ll need to write a custom walker.. I was hoping someone can help me with an easier solution or a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [`get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) rather than `wp_list_pages()` for this purpose.

The `get_pages()` function will return an *array of objects* of Pages, and you can use the array data to build your own HTML list. e.g.:

```
<?php
// Wrap in a function, for later output;
function wpse47989_list_pages() {
    // Get an array of pages using default arguments
    // See Codex for list of arguments
    $wpse47989_pages = get_pages();

    // Open the unordered list
    $page_list = '<ul>';

    // Loop through the results, and output an HTML list
    foreach ( $wpse47989_pages as $wpse47989_page ) {
        // Open the list item
        $page_list .= '<li>';
        // Open the link
        $page_list .= '<a href="' . $wpse47989->permalink . '">';
        // Link anchor text (post slug)
        $page_list .= $wpse47989_page->post_name;
        // Close the link
        $page_list .= '</a>';
        // Close the list item
        $page_list .= '</li>';
    }

    // Close the unordered list
    $page_list .= '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Then, of course, you just output the function wherever you want to display the list. (Note: this would be a good candidate for a custom Widget. You could even pass the function `get_pages()` arguments as Widget options.)

You may need to manipulate the foreach output for styling/etc.

Comment: Thanks Chip, this works great. I made a minor change to display the permalink of the pages:


`$page_list .= '<a href="' . get_page_link( $wpse47989->ID ) . '">';`

Comment: Glad it worked!